# How to place a toast

Tags: java, android

recently i got the the bmi calculator  for android from github
it is working perfctlty but if the there are no values inserted then the application is closing,
i tried to insert toast and check if the textviews are empty or it is = 0 in return to display a toast not to close the application.please help me in solving this.
here are the java files
**Mainactivity**

```
    package com.health.advicer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;

;

public class HealthAdvicer extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        View calculateButton = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Double weight = getValue(R.id.weight);
                Double height = getValue(R.id.height);
                Integer age = new Integer(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.age)).getText().toString());

                RadioGroup gender = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.gender);
                RadioButton selectedGender = (RadioButton) findViewById(gender.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

                Double bmr = Gender.valueOf((String)selectedGender.getText()).calculateBMR(weight, height, age);
                Double bmi = weight / (Math.pow(height/100, 2));
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.bmi_index)).setText(bmi.toString());
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.bmr_index)).setText(bmr.toString());
                findViewById(R.id.linearLayout3).setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
            }

            private Double getValue(int id) {
                return new Double(((EditText) findViewById(id)).getText()
                        .toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and it is also having another java file named gender.java and its contents are

```
package com.health.advicer;

public enum Gender {

Male(66, 13.7, 5.0, 6.8), Female(655, 9.6, 1.8, 4.7);

private Integer sumFactor;
private Double weightFactor;
private Double heightFactor;
private Double ageFactor;

private Gender(Integer sumFactor, Double weightFactor, Double heightFactor,
        Double ageFactor) {
    this.sumFactor = sumFactor;
    this.weightFactor = weightFactor;
    this.heightFactor = heightFactor;
    this.ageFactor = ageFactor;
}

public Double calculateBMR(Double weight, Double height, Integer age) {
    return sumFactor + (weightFactor * weight) + (heightFactor * height)
            - (ageFactor * age);
}

}
```

thank you

Comment: use system.out.println() it will work

Comment: would you please specify about the println() as iam little poor

Comment: Double getValue(int id){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

Answer (score 2):

to display simple toast use following code:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: where i need to place it i am not able to understand

Comment: You need to get reference for EditText and then check for value as follow:
         EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
         if(et.getText()==null ||et.getText().equals("")){
          //code to show toast
          return;
         }

Answer (score 1):

```
 Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
 toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); // last two args are X and Y
 toast.show();
```

The toast message can be placed by giving the values in **x and y** co-ordinates.

Comment: inside the given java code where i need to keep your suggested one .would please give me solution in detail